# Routing from OpenVPN client to main router: How?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, routing, openvpn

My Pi/OpenVPN settings:

```
IPv4 address for tun0: 10.8.0.1
IPv4 address for eth0: 192.168.222.20
IPv4 address of router: 192.168.222.1
```

The OpenVPN client (smartphone) needs to see the router for a specific app. However, it seems that it is stuck in the subnet of tun0 (10.8.0.1).

I guess I need some routing here, but I have no idea, where to even begin.

Edit: netstat -rn shows:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.222.1   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 tun0
192.168.222.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
192.168.222.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 eth0
```

sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward shows:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

nft list ruleset: nft not found (I would need to install it).

iptables-save shows:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun May 15 12:38:36 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [43:2748]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:128]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [34:2671]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [34:2671]
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 ! -d 10.8.0.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.178.30
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May 15 12:38:36 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Sun May 15 12:38:36 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [31:1132]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1111 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 179 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 1111 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m multiport --dports 546:547 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5335 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 5335 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun May 15 12:38:36 2022
```

Router is FritzBox 7530 AX

Edit: I changed from 192.168.178.0/24 to 192.168.222.0/24 because I thought it fixes the problem. I changed the other outputs accordingly.

Comment: Does `netstat -rn` show something like `192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp11s0` (it won't be exactly the same for you) that routes packets for the 192.168 subnet directly to your network interface and not to tun0?

Comment: I put the result of netstat -rn in the main question, but I don't know how to read it or how to route the traffic or even what to search for in Google

Comment: If I'm reading that right, you're not sending any traffic to tun0. One of your entries should have a gateway "10.8.0.1" so that most traffic is sent there. Visit a site like ipleak.net or something and see if openvpn is actually doing anything? I don't think it is.

Comment: @User123456789 There are a few things to check / do: 1. enable (sysctl) and allow (firewall, if any) IP forwarding; 2. Either set up NAT for the VPN subnet or add a static route for it on the router. You'd want to add the output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, `iptables-save`, and `nft list ruleset` to your question. If you would like some pointers on how to add static route on your router, please also supply the model.

Comment: I added the output. I have ufw installed, maybe it blocks the traffic? I opened up everything, so that normal internet with OpenVPN clients works. But the OpenVPN client should also see the router.

Comment: Btw what exactly do you mean by "see" the router? Note that if you are talking about something like multicast or some kind of L2 access/discovery, it's expected to not to work with at least tun OpenVPN. (Assuming this router has some kind of admin web page, can you reach `http://192.168.178.1` or `https://192.168.178.1` from a VPN client's web browser?) In any case, there's a chance that ufw blocks forwarding to the LAN IP subnet. I can't tell for sure without full `iptables-save` output. (Not familiar with `ufw` to know whether there's a simple ufw-specific way to find out.)

Comment: I posted the whole iptables-save output. Also, I changed from 192.168.178.0/24 to 192.168.222.0/24 because I thought it fixes the problem and updated the other outputs as well

Comment: Also, I currently can't reach the router in the web browser (192.168.222.1, with the new address). But I can't reach normal websites either, maybe something broke with the new IP address (…222.20) that PiHole is no longer reachable from OpenVPN. Ufw should be configured correctly, at least the right OpenVPN and PiHole port definitly is open. I also disabled ufw and there is no change, still doesn't work.

Comment: Update your SNAT rule. The forward chain/rules seems fine, so I have no idea why you can't access your router in particular.

Comment: I reinstalled OpenVPN which updated the SNAT rule (didn't know how to do otherwise). I now can access the router. But on the phone via cellular, the "FritzFon-App" (router access app for phone calls via VPN) can't access the router (maybe just a bug, since I can access the router in safari). In Wi-Fi, it all works fine with the app. Also, I still don't have internet, not even "8.8.8.8" in safari (should redirect to dns.google). This is not a DNS problem, the URL is shown. At least internet access worked before I changed to 192.168.222.0/24, but the mentioned app never worked in cellular

Comment: I now have internet again. I forgot to set up CDR (conditional forwarding) in PiHole Adminpanel » Settings » DNS » CDR. Now everythings works fine again, the router access is possible, but not with this specific app. But its possible to access the router for this specific task (phone calls) with cellular from a laptop and a different app. This means, this phone app has some sort of bug, because now, everything else works.